# SQL _ wildcard not working with unicode prefix N

Tags: sql, unicode, wildcard

`_ wildcard` works if I don't add unicode prefix 'N', but does not work if I add it.

For example

This will return correct value

```
Select * From TableA where Column1 is like '1_0'
```

This will not return any vlue

```
Select * From TableA where Column1 is like N'1_0'
```

And I try on SQL Server 2012, above two format will not work. I need to add a suffix of % to make it work:

```
Select * From TableA where Column1 is like '1_0%'
```

or

```
Select * From TableA where Column1 is like N'1_0%'
```

but not the result I want, cause it will return 1000,10001 as well.

Answer (score 0):

there're space, I use Rtrim() will solve the problem